# Is it permissible to pray for my own death?

Tags: dua, death

Is it permissible in Islam for someone to pray for themselves to die? Assuming you do nothing to purposefully bring about death on yourself.

Answer (score 6):

No it's not allowed to pray for death on themselves, even though we will all die one day.

The Prophet said =

> "None of you should wish for death because of a calamity befalling
> him; but if he has to wish for death, he should say: 'Allahumma ahini ma kanatil-hayatu khairantli wa tawaffani idha kanatil-wafatu khairanli - O Allah! Keep me
> alive as long as life is better for me, and let me die if death is
> better for me.'"

[(Sahih al-Bukhari)](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5671)

And the wording in Sahih Muslim =

> None among you should make a request for death, and do not call for it
> before it comes, for when any one of you dies, he ceases deeds and the
> life of a believer is not prolonged but for goodness.

[(Sahih Muslim)](http://sunnah.com/muslim/48/15)

Answer (score -2):

If life is hard you have to wish for death all lies to you and cheats on you uses you n throwing you and your family won’t let you be educated they can’t trust you what’s the use ooooo Allaah kill me as fast as you can .

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. Your answer could use references.